# How to add some additional DNS search domains without ignoring the DHCP ones?

Tags: macos, dns, network

I just want to add my own list of Search Domains but without overriding the ones returned by the DHCP?

As anyone would imagine I already tried to add them to Network > Advanced > DNS but adding them there it will override the ones from DHCP, which is not my intend.

It would be perfect if I could add them after the ones form DHCP, but I would also accept a solution that adds them after.

2nd try would be `/etc/resolv.conf` but the message from the file is as clear as it can be:

```
# This file is not used by the host name and address resolution
# or the DNS query routing mechanisms used by most processes on
# this Mac OS X system.
#
# This file is automatically generated.
```

Personally, I would send the guy who wrote this message to do some phone support for two months. So, he would learn to add some hints next time he documents things: where are you supposed to tune the settings? or include a link to a knowledge base article.

Still, I don't want something that is lost on minor OS X update.

How can I do this for OS X 10.7 ?

Comment: You might explain a bit more what you've tried and why entering search domains in the normal place isn't what you want. Specifically - do you want your search domains to be searched before the DHCP ones or after the supplied ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try adding/appending them to `/etc/resolv.conf`? You cannot add them to the end of the list manually, delimiting with a comma in Lion? It seems to work in 10.6, it adds it in addition to the DHCP supplied ones, and the entire lot of them show up in resolv.conf instantly.

Perhaps this won't work for your purposes, but why not just manually add the ones DHCP supplied and the ones you want to add and save them in System Preferences?  Then you won't need to worry about overwriting anything as you will be manually adding them.  I don't suppose your domain is going to change names very frequently.

I can tell you as of Snow Leopard mDNSResponder (Bonjour) handles all the DNS (not just Multicast DNS).

Comment: `resolve.conf` usage is deprecated, being documented inside the file.

Comment: This doesn't work and should not be the accepted answer. @Yobert's answer works great and does _exactly_ what the asker wanted.

Answer (score 7):

Just put a file in /etc/resolver/ with a name such as "searchappend" with these contents:

```
search example.com
```

Just don't name the file "com" or some other valid TLD. This works because of OSX's resolver magic.  For more info, read through the documentation on your mac with this command:

```
man 5 resolver
```

I have a file there called "consul" that looks like this:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
port 8600
search consul
```

That magically makes it so .consul is appended to the search path, and any resolving for .consul TLDs uses my local nameserver.

Comment: Links broken, cannot find a replacement.

Comment: I agree that the links are broken, but this worked for me on 10.13.6. I had to create /etc/resolver first. The file I created contained only `search mydomain.com`. The additional search domain applied to all network adapters and appended to the existing DHCP search domains.

Comment: This doesn't work for me anymore in Mojave. :(

Comment: You may be able to do `man 5 resolver` on your mac? the link was to a web version of that same man page.

Comment: Confirmed to work on 10.15.6 (Catalina). Anything in /etc/resolver/* was added to the active resolver configuration. Perfect for adding a global search path for always-on-VPN. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Is this supposed to work for the `local` TLD? I want to access other LAN computers without adding `.local` - but unfortunately this didn't work. I also added `local` to the search domains in Network Settings without success.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `networksetup` command, and add the additional search domains in an array on the comand line: From the man page:

```
-setsearchdomains networkservice domain1 [domain2] [...]

Use this command to designate the search domain for the specified
<networkservice>. You can list any number of search domains
(replace domain1, domain2, and so on with the name of a local
domain). If you want to clear all search domain entries for the
specified network service, type aemptya in place of the domain
```

So:

```
sudo networksetup -setsearchdomains Wi-Fi legacydomain.com secondlegacydomain.com additionaldomain.org evenmoresearchdomain.net
```

this invocation should have the proper order.

Comment: While I love the command line approach I have to say that running this does override the DNS domains received from the DHCP server, so is not a proper solution. I still want to be able able to used them, just to add mine on top of bottom of the list. Need an automated solution.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to do this for a VPN connection.

Firstly, find DNS keys in data store:

```
echo "list .*/DNS"| scutil
```

You can look at each key using `show <key>` command, as in

```
> show State:/Network/Global/DNS
<dictionary> {
  DomainName : example.com
  SearchDomains : <array> {
    0 : my.example.com
    1 : your.example.com
  }
  ServerAddresses : <array> {
    0 : 8.8.8.8
    1 : 4.4.4.4
  }
}
```

As I said, I was changing for my VPN connection and so initially ended up with a script like so:

```
sudo scutil <<HERE
get State:/Network/Service/com.cisco.anyconnect/DNS
d.show
d.remove SearchDomains
d.add SearchDomains my.example.com your.example.com new.example.com 
set State:/Network/Service/com.cisco.anyconnect/DNS
show State:/Network/Service/com.cisco.anyconnect/DNS
exit
HERE
```

To complete the picture, as per the original question then:

```
#!/bin/ksh
KEYS="State:/Network/Service/utun1/DNS State:/Network/Service/com.cisco.anyconnect/DNS"
append_domains="fake.example.com"

# Check for known keys in database
for DNS in $KEYS; do
    key=$(echo list $DNS | scutil)
    if [[ $key != "  No such key" ]]; then
       break
    fi
    found=$DNS
done
if [[ -z $found ]]; then
    print -u2 "unable to find DNS key!"
    exit
fi

# Read current settings from key
typeset -A data
thistype="unknown"
print "get $DNS\nd.show" | scutil | while read type colon value rest; do
     case $type in
     (DomainName)   data[$type]=$value;;
     (SearchDomains|ServerAddresses)    thistype="$type";;
     ([0-9])        data[$thistype]="${data[$thistype]}$value ";;
     (*)        thistype="unknown";;
     esac
done

# Check to see if the domains are already listed
domains=${data[SearchDomains]%% }
for domain in $append_domains; do
    found=""
    for current in $domains; do
        if [[ $domain == $current ]]; then
       found=$domain
    fi
    done
    if [[ -z $found ]]; then
        add="${add}${domain} "
    fi
done

# If there is nothing to add then we are done.
if [[ -z $add ]]; then
    exit
fi

DOMAINS="$domains ${add%% }"
echo Replacing SearchDomains with $DOMAINS
echo on service $DNS

sudo scutil <<HERE
get $DNS
d.remove SearchDomains
d.add SearchDomains $DOMAINS
set $DNS
show $DNS
exit
HERE
```

macOS Mojave - 10.14.6

Answer (score 1):

Add them to System Preferences > Network > Advanced > | DNS |

(Any particular reason for this being down-voted?  It does exactly what the requester is asking for and doesn't require the use of a Terminal.)

Comment: Because he wrote that he didn't want to override the DHCP DNS entries.  Plus you would have to add them to every interface.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your router provides its set of DNS servers, add its IP address (your router’s) to your **DNS Servers** list. Add your own DNS servers below it.

Your computer will query your router first, then cycle through the ones you defined manually.